# Prevent form submission using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, joomla2.5

I am validating my form using jquery as below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#adminform').validate({

        rules: {
          name: {
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 30,
            required: true
          },
          username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 30
          }
        },
        highlight: function(label) {
            jQuery(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label
                .text('OK!').addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
        },
        messages:{

          name: {
            required: "Enter your name"
          },
          username: {
            required: "Enter a username"
          } 
       }
      });     
});
```

now how should I prevent the form from submission if the rules are not meet?

When I click the submit button nothing should happen.

Comment: Take a look at your JS console and check for errors.

Comment: You are using a plugin called `validate`. Your code is incomplete. Please post the whole code so we could help

Comment: @Ahmad Alfy to be honest i have more fields out of which i have just shown two of them here. but i feel whether i have 2 or 10 fields, the code is just to add rules and the corresponding messages if invalid. so the code will look like above only.

Answer (score 2):

To stop a form being submitted you use:

```
return false;
```

When you know the input is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

`Prevent form submission using jQuery?`

```
$('#myFormId').submit(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
 });
```

OR:

```
$('#myFormId').submit(function()
{
    return false;
});
```

Comment: i tried this way: jQuery('#adminform').submit(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    });

Answer (score 1):

Prevent the submit event and remain on the screen

```
e.preventDefault();
```

what about this?

Comment: where and how to put the e.preventDefault();

Comment: i am getting something like this: {"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0x8f7f56c>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0x934d24c>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}"}

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfect just a submit trigger needed : **http://jsfiddle.net/uUdWN/**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#adminform').validate({
    rules: {
        name: {
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 30,
            required: true
        },
        username: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5,
            maxlength: 30
        }
    },
    highlight: function(label) {
        jQuery(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
    },
    success: function(label) {
        label.text('OK!').addClass('valid').closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
    },
    messages: {
        name: {
            required: "Enter your name"
        },
        username: {
            required: "Enter a username"
        }
    }
});


$("#adminform").submit(); // <-------------just triggered submit

});
```

Comment: i added jQuery("#adminform").submit(); but that didn't help me